# Travar botão enviar quando nenhum upload de arquivo tiver sido realizado

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Então pessoal, tenho um componente fileUpload do primefaces para fazer o upload de arquivos. Acontece que mesmo com o required="true", se o usuário clicar em enviar sem ter feito o upload de nenhum arquivo o sistema envia.

```
 <p:fileUpload
     required="true"
     requiredMessage="Comprovante ou declaração de vínculo de trabalho: item obrigatório"
     fileUploadListener="#{comprovanteBean.uploadArquivoDespesaTransporte}" update="@form" 
     label="Arquivo" uploadLabel="Enviar" cancelLabel="Cancelar" 
     allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$/"
     invalidFileMessage="São permitidos apenas arquivos do tipo: jpeg, jpg, png, pdf)"
     sizeLimit="1048576"invalidSizeMessage="O tamanho máximo permitido é de 1 MB." 
     fileLimit="1">
</p:fileUpload>



<p:commandButton value="Enviar comprovantes" update="@form" ajax="false" action="#{comprovanteBean.finalizarInscricao()}">
    <f:param name="inscricaoFinalizada" value="true"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

No site do primefaces o botão deles está travado, porém não ativa quando faço o upload, daí nem deu pra mim pegar o código deles: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como não permitir que o usuário se cadastre sem enviar esse arquivo??

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar habilitar o botão de enviar somente se houver um envio de arquivo com sucesso. Acho que o mais simples é usar uma flag, inicialmente setada como `true`:

No XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton value="Enviar comprovantes" update="@form" ajax="false" action="#{comprovanteBean.finalizarInscricao()}" disabled="#{comprovanteBean.semArquivos}">
    <f:param name="inscricaoFinalizada" value="true"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

No Bean:

```
private boolean semArquivos = true;

public boolean isSemArquivos() {
    return this.semArquivos;
}

public boolean setSemArquivos(boolean semArquivos) {
    this.semArquivos = semArquivos;
}

public void uploadArquivoDespesaTransporte(FileUploadEvent event) {
    //Executar o seu método já existente
    setSemArquivos(getArquivos().isEmpty());
}
```